# restricted pages redirects 301 moved permanently after http to https transfer

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, https, joomla

I am using joomla platform. I recently redirected my site from http to https using .htaccess.
redirection was successful but when I try to access restricted pages it gives status code as 301 Moved Permanently, the joomla pages which are restricted are redirected Permanently.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http

    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

    RewriteBase /

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I am not 100% certain, so it's a comment, not an answer.  Remove the blank line between RewriteCond and the RewriteRule.  RewriteCond sets a condition for the following RewriteRule, but I wonder if the empty line does not break that association.  This would force the RewrireRule to run for every request.

Comment: If you are Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  You are welcome to post all Joomla related or Joomla extension related questions on JSE.